# Make Android jenkins build fail if tests fail

Tags: android, ant, junit, hudson, jenkins

I have seen several post regarding making a build in Jenkins fail if the unit test execution fail (e.g. this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681880/how-to-make-jenkins-display-fail-if-one-of-the-ant-tests-fail)). It turns out that by default Jenkins reports builds with failing tests as `unstable` and some people do not like that. This, however, will be perfectly fine for me. I just want to be able to easily differentiate builds with passing tests from such with failing tests.

And here is the catch: **I am developing for Android** so my build is configured following [this page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+an+Android+app+and+test+project). Basically the tests are run with the following command:

```
ant all clean emma debug install test
```

As result coverage report is generated and published in Jenkins.

All posts I have read about configuring the Jenkins result according to tests results
were dealing with ant task manipulation. However, if we look at the android `build.xml` the Android tests are run with adb command: `adb shell am instrument ...`. I don't know how to configure this command to print the tests results. It can be configured to print the coverage report. I have already done that, but was never able to make the build fail according to the coverage report.

I hope somebody else also faced the same problem and managed to solve it. Any guidance will be most appreciated.

Comment: Would [this be helpful](http://code.google.com/p/the-missing-android-xml-junit-test-runner/)? The idea is to produce junit reports that Jenkins understands.

Comment: @malenkiy_scot Thank you for that comment. This might work. I will try it out in the following days.

Comment: @malenkiy_scot Please post you comment as an answer. I want to give you the bounty. My problem is not yet solved, but this is at least good direction.

Comment: Done - I originally did not want to provide it as an answer as I have not personally tried it. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

This is possible, configure the server using the following documentation:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Android+Emulator+Plugin

See "Parsing monkey output" in the link.

Addition, Jenkins can test instrumentation, below have a link of a good place to start in the learning of instrumentation:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/testing/helloandroid_test.html

I hope it is useful.

[image: screenshot of my project jenkins]

Comment: "http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/testing/helloandroid_test.html" is now broken

Answer (score 2):

Consider using ['the-missing-android-xml-junit-test-runner'](http://code.google.com/p/the-missing-android-xml-junit-test-runner/) - the idea being to produce jUnit reports that Jenkins understands. Disclaimer: I do have no personal experience with *adb*. However, I do know from experience that Jenkins deals with properly generated jUnit reports very gracefully.