# How to mark jenkins build failed if JUnit test has an error?

Tags: java, jenkins, junit

I need a workaround for this [Jenkins issue (JUnit report doesn't distinguish between test failures and errors)](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-4951).

I thought of using the [Groovy Postbuild Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin#GroovyPostbuildPlugin-Example9%28thankstoKenBertelson%29) but it looks like this Jenkins "philosophy" is deeply integrated, i.e. [TestResultAction](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/tasks/junit/TestResultAction.html) doesn't even provide the tests in error.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for a work around I think that you can create simple script for parsing xunit file and in case find error use exit 1 for mark build failed. Look in the similar [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22814559/how-when-does-execute-shell-mark-a-build-as-failure-in-jenkins)

Comment: I'll try this and if it is working I will accept this answer.