# Build step 'Windows PowerShell' marked build as failure, why?

Tags: powershell, jenkins

Below are three PowerShell Commands run in Jenkins and the build result. Why it fails? Which command could be failing? I've read this post: [How/When does Execute Shell mark a build as failure in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22814559/how-when-does-execute-shell-mark-a-build-as-failure-in-jenkins), but couldn't figure out. I am not familiar with MS stuffs.

Command 1:

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" "$env:WORKSPACE\ETL\OnePnL.sln" /Build
```

Command2:

```
###########################
# Deploy SSIS package           #
###########################  
$csource ="$env:WORKSPACE\ETL\Project Type 0\bin\DEFAULT\OnePnL.ispac"
$cserver = "SSASDBDEV01"
$cdest = "/SSISDB/OnePnL/OnePnL"    
echo $env:GIT_BRANCH    
if ($env:GIT_BRANCH  -like '*master*')
{
   # Call IS Deployment Wizard
   echo "Deploying SSIS package to $cdest on $cserver"    
   # "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\ISDeploymentWizard.exe" "/Silent /SourcePath:""$csource""    #/DestinationPath:""$cdest"" /DestinationServer:""$cserver""" -Wait
   Start-Process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\ISDeploymentWizard.exe" "/Silent /SourcePath:""$csource""    /DestinationPath:""$cdest"" /DestinationServer:""$cserver""" -Wait
}
```

Command 3:

```
#####################
# Copy Files to O: drive #
#####################

#Make build directory

#$outputparentdir = "\\orion\Shared\AppUpload\ApplicationPackage\OnePnL Cube\SSIS Jenkins Builds"
$outputparentdir = "\\inv\Shared\Transfer - Deleted Weekly\Jenkins\BI\OnePnL\SSIS Jenkins builds"
$outputdir = "$outputparentdir\${env:GIT_BRANCH}\Build ${env:BUILD_NUMBER}"
echo "Branch"
echo ${env:GIT_BRANCH}

echo "Output directory"
echo $outputdir 

if (!(Test-Path "$outputparentdir"))
{
  mkdir $outputparentdir
}

mkdir $outputdir

ROBOCOPY "$env:WORKSPACE\ETL\Project Type 0\bin\DEFAULT" "$outputdir" /E /v

echo "Done Copy"
```

Build result:

```
[OnePnL SSIS] $ powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy ByPass "& 'C:\Users\SVC_TE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson3790190217372968147.ps1'"

Microsoft (R) Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Version 11.0.50727.1.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.
------ Build started: Project: OnePnL, Configuration: DEFAULT ------
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
[OnePnL SSIS] $ powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy ByPass "& 'C:\Users\SVC_TE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson2769520726749517170.ps1'"
origin/release
[OnePnL SSIS] $ powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy ByPass "& 'C:\Users\SVC_TE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson7860003244522954499.ps1'"
Branch
origin/release
Output directory
\\inv\Shared\Transfer - Deleted Weekly\Jenkins\BI\OnePnL\SSIS Jenkins builds\origin/release\Build 74


    Directory: \\inv\Shared\Transfer - Deleted Weekly\Jenkins\BI\OnePnL\SSIS 
    Jenkins builds\origin\release


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                              
----                -------------     ------ ----                              
d----        10/26/2015   4:29 PM            Build 74                          

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Monday, October 26, 2015 4:29:01 PM
   Source : D:\te_jenprodslave_1\workspace\Trade_Efficiencies\BI\OnePnL SSIS\ETL\Project Type 0\bin\DEFAULT\
     Dest : \\inv\Shared\Transfer - Deleted Weekly\Jenkins\BI\OnePnL\SSIS Jenkins builds\origin\release\Build 74\

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /V /S /E /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                       1    D:\te_jenprodslave_1\workspace\Trade_Efficiencies\BI\OnePnL SSIS\ETL\Project Type 0\bin\DEFAULT\
        New File          516475    OnePnL.ispac
  0%  
 25%  
 50%  
 76%  
100%  

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :         1         0         0         0         0         0
   Files :         1         1         0         0         0         0
   Bytes :   504.3 k   504.3 k         0         0         0         0
   Times :   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00


   Speed :            43039583 Bytes/sec.
   Speed :            2462.744 MegaBytes/min.
   Ended : Monday, October 26, 2015 4:29:01 PM

Done Copy


Build step 'Windows PowerShell' marked build as failure
```

Comment: Asking the community to debug your code and not giving them _any_ hint as to the problem is usually met with downvotes. I understand that you are _not familiar with MS stuffs_ but that mean you just need to at least try and figure it out for yourself.

Comment: its always nice to let the answerer know it worked or not worked

Answer (score 9):

The answer is sort of in the post you linked.

> the **exit code of last command** of the Jenkin's Execute Shell build step is what determines the success/failure of the Build Step

I get that you understand that much, but what makes it come into play is the [return code for robocopy](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/954404) which was you last command. While the link is for server 2008 I won't be surprised if they are OS common.

```
Value   Description
0       No files were copied. No failure was encountered. No files were mismatched. The files already exist in the destination directory; therefore, the copy operation was skipped.
1       All files were copied successfully.
```

If all the files were copied successfully then the return code is 1. *Anything* other than 0 is reported as a failure by the build step as we have read in the linked question.

---

I think what you need to do is check the return code of robocopy and change it.

To check it you need to look at a [PowerShell automatic variable $?](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx)

> $?
>   Contains the execution status of the last operation. It contains
>          TRUE if the last operation succeeded and FALSE if it failed.

So the last couple of lines could be...

```
ROBOCOPY "$env:WORKSPACE\ETL\Project Type 0\bin\DEFAULT" "$outputdir" /E /v
If($?){exit 0}
```

What this should do is take any non zero result from robocopy and force the script to return true. Again, be aware that this would return OK for all return codes. If this is not desirable then you could easily build some logic for certain codes.

I cannot really test this code as I do not have your environment but in theory it should work or at least get you started on where you need to be.

Comment: The [PSDeploy](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PSDeploy) Fileshare provider uses Robocopy and this resolved my build issue in Jenkins. Which even though PsDeploy wraps the robocopy exit codes and the function succeeds, Jenkins still fails the build on the non-zero success exit code from the internal robocopy...