# Powershell Script not getting failed in Jenkins

Tags: shell, powershell, jenkins, invoke-command

I have downloaded [SSH-Sessions by Joakim Svendsen](http://www.powershelladmin.com/w/images/6/60/SSH-Sessions.zip) which uses [SSH.NET](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET) and installed the PowerShell module in the Jenkins Windows server

In Jenkins, I have the following PowerShell script:

```
Import-Module SSH-Sessions

$lastExitCode = 0
$devApp1 = "10.0.0.1"
$devApp2 = "10.0.0.2"

Write-Output "Deployment started in $devApp1......"

New-SshSession -ComputerName $devApp1 -Username test -Password test@123
$return = Invoke-SshCommand -ComputerName $devApp1  -Command "cd /NFS_DATA/autodeploy_scripts && echo test@123 | ./autodeploy.sh"

$return | Get-Member

if ($lastExitCode -ne 0)
{
    Write-Output $lastExitCode
    exit 1;
}
else
{
    Write-Output $lastExitCode
    exit 0;
}
```

The shell script contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="/NFS_DATA/autodeploy_scripts/test.log"
if [ -f "$file" ]
then
        echo "$file found."
        exit 0;
else
        echo "$file not found."
        exit 1;
fi
```

The problem is that the Jenkins job doesn't get failed when the file is not found. The Jenkins output is:

> ```
> > Deployment started in 10.0.0.1...... Successfully connected to
> > 10.0.0.01
> > 10.0.0.01 had an error:
>
> Finished: SUCCESS
> ```

After some suggestions I wrote the following PowerShell script using [Posh-SSH](https://github.com/darkoperator/Posh-SSH). I'm also getting an error for this one, though it's different.

```
#Import-Module SSH-Sessions
Import-Module Posh-SSH

# Setup static variables
$devApp1="10.0.0.1"
$devApp2="10.0.0.2"
$username = "test"
$password = "test@123"
$command = "cd /NFS_DATA/autodeploy_scripts && echo Hybris@123 | ./autodeploy.sh"

Write-Output "Deployment started in $devApp1..."

# Setup PSCredentials
$secPasswd   = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $secPasswd) 
echo $credentials

# Estalbish new SSH session automatically accepting new SSH keys
$session = New-SSHSession -Computername $devApp1 -Credential $credentials -Acceptkey:$true

# Invoke command to be run on/in the SSH session
$output = Invoke-SSHCommand -SSHSession $session -Command $command

Write-Output "Returned Output from the Command: "
Write-Output $output.Output
Write-Output "Last Exit Status: "
Write-Output $output.ExitStatus
```

Getting the error message as:

[image: Posh-SSH script result]

The same code works in my local laptop, but fails in the Jenkins server.

I think in Jenkins server, due to Windows security restrictions, will not store the `$secpasswd` that is retrieved from the PSCredential. This causes only the username to be supplied to POSH.

How can I either fix those issues? How should I hardcode the password?

Comment: My assumption would be that nothing is happening because you're not passing on that error code from the PowerShell environment to Jenkins. As it is the PowerShell script exists with 0 unless there is an error while importing/establishing the session or Invoking the command. You would need to evaluate and return the code from `Invoke-SSHCommand`.

Comment: I'm new to powershell.. How to evaluate the Invoke-SSHCommand output

Comment: That would depend on how it's implemented. Look into the documentation for those cmdlets or play around with it. A good start would be to save what's returned to a variable. So `$return = Invoke-SSHCommand ...`. After that you could use [`Get-Member`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176854.aspx) to get more information or just let it print to the screen and have a look. Mind you that something like [`$?`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634115/what-is-in-powershell) might be insufficient as the cmdlet itself might actually work fine, though the commands within error.

Comment: I'm clueless how to use Get-Member to evaluate the InvokeSSHCommand

Comment: The link actually contains an example for that. Shouldn't be that hard and you could also use it on the variable. You should do this on an interactive PowerShell and not in the script. Figure out what the invoke returns and adjust your script afterwards. As an example the default `Invoke-Command` cmdlet. You could also try to run `Invoke-SSHCommand -?` or `Get-Help -Full Invoke-SSHCommand` or use `-Examples` to get more information about how the cmdlet is supposed to work.

Comment: I tried with Get-Member, but unable to fix the issue. Is there any other way to fix it.

Comment: What did you try? What additional information did you discover? What were the properties and was there information about the return value of the cmdlet?

Comment: i have updated the question by providing Get-Member output and the powershell not dislpaying the error message given from shell script inside the linux box. It displays the success message but not the failure message

Comment: Did you even try to understand what `Get-Member` do? With your call of `echo $return | Get-Member`, you're telling PowerShell to transform `$return` into a string and afterwards you're checking out the attributes .. which of course are the attributes every string attribute has.

Comment: No, you're not. The original link for the documentation has quite a bit of information. If you're also new to programming as a whole it could be different. Sorry though if my words were a bit harsh. If you're not actually using Posh-SSH you might be using [this](http://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki/SSH_from_PowerShell_using_the_SSH.NET_library#Invoke-SshCommand) (you never said what script you're using). In which case the command seems to only return a string. The link contains an example on how to get output and exit status.

Comment: I have downloaded http://www.powershelladmin.com/w/images/6/60/SSH-Sessions.zip and installed powershell module in the Jenkins windows server

Comment: I used Posh-SSH module now and updated the question with the error message

Comment: The credentials shouldn't be an issue. What's most likely happening is that Posh-SSH isn't importing successfully. Did you use the Windows built in zip viewer to extract the files? Check that they aren't blocked. You can do this by checking the file properties and unblocking the files. As there is a `Unblock-File` cmdlet you could use it to unblock all files in a directory. See also [Easily Unblock All Files in a Directory Using PowerShell by Hey, Scripting Guy!](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/09/14/easily-unblock-all-files-in-a-directory-using-powershell/)

Comment: Unblock-File works in PowerShell 3.0 ... I'm using powershell 2.0 version. I also checked the file properties, its not blocked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've never stated where those commands are coming from, I'm going to assume you're using [Posh-SSH](https://github.com/darkoperator/Posh-SSH). By looking at [this article](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/07/03/posh-ssh-open-source-ssh-powershell-module/) about it, the solution would probably be:

```
$dev_app1="10.00.00.01"
$dev_app2="10.00.00.02"

echo "Deployment started in $dev_app1......"
Import-Module SSH-Sessions
New-SshSession -ComputerName $dev_app1 -Username test -Password test@123
$result = Invoke-SshCommand -ComputerName $dev_app1  -Command "cd /NFS_DATA/autodeploy_scripts && echo test@123 | ./autodeploy.sh"

Write-Output "Returned Output from the Command: "
Write-Output $result.Output
Write-Output "Last Exit Status: "
Write-Output $result.ExitStatus

if($result.ExitStatus -ne 0){
    exit $result.ExitStatus;
}
```

The `if` could be left out, it's just there for demonstration purposes. After all the exit status would be 0 otherwise.

The correct way to use `Get-Member` to get information about `$result` (in case this does not work) would be: `$result | Get-Member`. That will output the general attributes of whatever kind of object `$result` is.

As it would appear you're [running this](http://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki/SSH_from_PowerShell_using_the_SSH.NET_library#Invoke-SshCommand). You would need to run the following to get the objects:

```
$result = $SshSessions."$dev_app1".RunCommand('cd /NFS_DATA/autodeploy_scripts && echo test@123 | ./autodeploy.sh')
```

You'd use this instead of the `Invoke-SshCommand` and would need to change `$result.Output` to `$result.Result`.

Comment: I have used `$result | Get-Member` , it displays the general attribute. How to proceed further

Comment: Either read the documentation on what those attributes mean or think about it. An attribute named `Output` probably will contain the output of the command executed by `Invoke-SshCommand`. So with your example script I'd expect the attribute to contain a text saying `... not found`. If it does have an attribute `ExitStatus` check whenever it's 0 or 1 and possibly force the error to check whenever it changes to 1. After that use that information to let the script indicate an error (possibly by exiting with a non zero exit code).

Comment: I have downloaded powershelladmin.com/w/images/6/60/SSH-Sessions.zip and installed powershell module in the Jenkins windows server

Comment: I used Posh-SSH module now and updated the question with the error message

Comment: `$result = $SshSessions."$dev_app1".RunCommand('cd /NFS_DATA/autodeploy_scripts && echo test@123 | ./autodeploy.sh')` and `Write-Output $result.Result` works fine. How to fetch the exit code

Comment: Does `$result.ExitStatus` have a valid value? If you look at the [documentation](http://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki/SSH_from_PowerShell_using_the_SSH.NET_library#Invoke-SshCommand_Example) that should contain the `ExitStatus` of the script. If it does you might have to change your termination. But you would have a stepping stone. You could also try to check the value by using `Write-Output "'$($result.Output)'"`. If it ends up being `''` you might have a null value. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33358242/build-step-windows-powershell-marked-build-as-failure-why) might be helpful?

Comment: It Works now. `Write-Output $result.ExitStatus` returns the exit code given in shell script