# py.test in Jenkins: No tests found in slack. Where I'm wrong?

Tags: python, jenkins, slack

I keep receiving an error when run Build. py.tests in jenkins:

jenkins execute shell:

```
#!/bin/sh
py.test tests || true
```

it starts. and after it finished I see next log:

```
   Started by user manny
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/web-services tests
> git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
> git config remote.origin.url https://example.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://example.org/m.git
 ...
 ...
[web-services tests] $ /bin/sh /tmp/hudson1759686215204688979.sh
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.5.1, pytest-2.9.1, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1
rootdir: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/web-services tests/tests, inifile: 
plugins: asyncio-0.3.0
collected 99 items / 4 errors

tests/bll/test_action_manager.py ......  //here goes list of tests
...


===== 3 failed, 75 passed, 1 skipped, 20 xfailed, 4 error in 76.85 seconds =====
Finished: SUCCESS
```

jenkins notify Slack:

```
web-services tests - #44 Back to normal after 19 min (</job/web-services%20tests/44/|Open>)
No Tests found.
```

No tests found. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the log, we can see that the python script has failed

**`collected 99 items / 4 errors`**

And from Jenkins point of view, if any error is encountered, it will give failure as Jenkins uses  `/bin/sh -xe` by default.

So by adding the `#!/bin/sh` before calling the python script might help in resolving this issue :

```
    #!/bin/sh
    py.test tests
```

Comment: it works/ thankyou!! and "collected 99 items / 4 errors".... 4 tests which are red.

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins marks the build success/failed depending on the exit code. 0 is success, else failed.

Exitcode of Py.Test is 0 when there are no errors. When there are 1 or more errors, not 0 (maybe 1, no idea exactly).

Solution:

- Wrap your call into a seperate shellscript and ignore the exitcode
- Change Jenkins job to `'your command || true'`

Comment: thank you.I am very new in it. Put like this:  py.test tests || true  ???
could you write code what I should use?

Comment: Depends on Windows/Linux, but that's what I found, I used the seperate shellscript for tests so I had them in VersionControl. For Linux: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22814559/how-when-does-execute-shell-mark-a-build-as-failure-in-jenkins

Answer (score 0):

Run the same test manually (outside of Jenkins) and check the error there.
Could be a problem is test collection, or just a test failure itself.

Also: please post full logs so we can better check what is going on